Teradata equivalent GOTO statement in Google Big Query
Wile migrating  from Teradata to Big Query I came across few Teradata BTEQ statements where we have GOTO statements to control the flows as per logic. We do have many such GOTO statements in between across the BTEQ file.
.IF ACTIVITYCOUNT = 0 THEN .GOTO ERROR;
.IF ACTIVITYCOUNT > 0 THEN .GOTO INSERT_ME;
Do we have any equivalent in Google Big query to handle such logics.
I used IF EXISTS in the code, it will work only if we have 1 or 2 GOTO statements. But If we have multiple flows using GOTO then it is not possible to implement using IF EXISTS.
Any one please help with implementation of GOTO in Big Query.

Generally when moving from a language that supports goto/label you will want to rething the entire flow of the program to use if,while, and other more modern patterns to program flow. While porting the code is the perfect time to get away from goto/label pattern. If you share the entire bteq perhaps we can help restructure it to a better pattern.
